# Merge and extend JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help - I want to merge and extend JavaScript objects in a way like in example below:

```
var objects = [{
        id: 1,
        fruits: "apple"
    },{
        id: 1,
        fruits: "bannana"
    },{
        id: 2,
        fruits: "tangerine"
    },{
        id: 2,
        fruits: "plum"
    }];
```

and to have results like:

```
var results = [{
        id: 1,
        fruits: ["apple", "bannana"]
    },{
        id: 2,
        fruits: ["tangerine", "plum"]
    }];
```

Is there any JavaScript, jQuery or easy custom solution to do it? It is different situation then here [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) or also $.expand() does not do here what I want.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, $.extend() doesn't work in a way I showed.

Comment: Try something then come back

Comment: `friuts` vs `rat`? just a typo?

Comment: The question is not duplicate... please reopen it

Comment: Yes, it is not duplicate, thanks. I read this posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically but my problem is different.